# GoAccess custom forwarded log parsing

Tags: goaccess

I am currently using `goaccess-1.0.2`.  I have installed it on an Amazon Linux box.  The box which it resides has customized logs that were forwarded from an `Apache WebApp Server`. What I have tried to accomplish but can't seem to figure out is how to get `GoAccess` to parse our customized log.

Here is an example of the custom forwarded WebApp Log entry:

```
Jun 24 00:00:41 directory1 httpd-access: 55.117.170.95 www.URLaddress.com - [24/Jun/2016:00:00:41 -0700] "GET /sites/all/themes/somthing_on_demand/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "ht
tps://www.IPaddress.com/my_account/yum" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "SESSb9948a0b21e4d377a7d82f6adbf86c91=l
on7pgjlikml7q4tq954ejiao1; cookie_js=1; __utma=23285183.1119616966.1452095139.1468883973.1468963151.39; __utmb=23285183.500.10.1468963151; __utmc=23285183; __utmz=23285183.1468963151.39.39.utmcsr=fyi.URLaddress.com|utm
ccn=(r/INFOSEC-MAXLEN-256" "-" 57630
```

Here are a few log-formats I have tried:

```
log-format %^ %^ %^ "%h %^ %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%R\" \"%u\" \"%^\" \"%^\" %D"

log-format "%h %{Host}i %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}x %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{SHORT_COOKIE}e\" \"%{X-Forwarded-For}i\" %D"

log-format "%h %{Host}i %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{SHORT_COOKIE}e\" \"%{X-Forwarded-For}i\" %D"
```

I thought I would ignore the date and time format using `%^` then use date format  `%m %d`  and time format  `%T`  .

I am very new at this and could really use help.  Thank you for your feedback in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this, it works for me:

```
goaccess -f access.log --log-format='%^:%^:%^: %h %v %^[%d:%t %^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u" "%^" "%^" %D' --date-format='%d/%b/%Y' --time-format='%T'
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I've used the format above, it actually started to parse.  I'm now troubleshooting the following.  

GoAccess - version 1.0.2 - Jul 25 2016 15:16:33
Config file: /usr/local/etc/goaccess.conf

Fatal error has occurred
Error occured at: src/goaccess.c - main - 1230
Nothing valid to process. Verify your date/time/log format.

When I find a solution, I will post for others.

Comment: Thank you again.  It worked.  I had to remove the single apostrophes.

Comment: Thank you again.  It worked but not directly in the terminal. I had to go to ***sudo nano /usr/local/etc/goacess.conf*** and unhashed the Apache Time Format and Date-Format to match the above.  Then in the Log Format Configuration, I changed the NCSA Combined Log Format with Virtual Host default configuration to match the one you provided.  Just took out the single quotes.  Then I ran ***goaccess -f <log directory> -a*** and it worked perfectly.  I really appreciate it!